# How to create "spiky" 3D arrow tips?

Tags: graphics3d

The following code does pretty much exactly what I want except that the lines stick out of the arrow tips - see picture below.  Is there a way to fix this so that one sees "spiky" arrow tips?  I don't really understand why this happens because the position is already set to 1 and increasing this values gives me an error message.

```
p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
  RegionFunction -> (#3^2 + #4^2 <= 1 &), Ticks -> None, Boxed -> False,
  ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1] &), Axes -> False, Mesh -> 21, PlotPoints -> 50];
f[u_, v_] := {Cos[u]*Sin[v], Sin[u]*Sin[v], Cos[v]};
q1 = Graphics3D[
   Table[Module[{w = f[u Pi/16, v Pi/16]}, {Thick, Black, Arrowheads[{{0.03, 1}}],
     Arrow[Tube[{w, 2*w}]]}], {u, 3, 7}, {v, 4, 7}]];
Show[p1, q1, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 ViewPoint -> {-1.48, 2.33, 2.05}, ViewVertical -> {0.21, -0.29, 1.94}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: works fine in v9 (windows 10) and v12 (wolfram cloud). You might consider using the second argument of `Arrow` i.e. the form `Arrow[Tube[{w, 2*w}], s]` to have the tube ends set back by s from the first and last coordinates.

Comment: Prompted by your comment, I upgraded to v12 (I was using v11.3 on Windows 10) and the problem is indeed gone.  Seems this was some glitch in v11. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, interesting! Finally this got fixed! It has been a long-standing annoyance to me, not a one-release-only glitch.